# EJS layouts on Express 3

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am having some problem with the EJS layout file on Express 3. Express just can't seem to find the layout for rendering. It just skips the layout.ejs totally which means that the output misses out of all the stylesheets and such.

```
res.render('login', { user: req.user });
```

and the configuration part,

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and in the layout.ejs I have added the body tag,

```
<%- body %>
```

I have been trying out Jade before and it worked just fine, so the problem is just EJS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `login.ejs` look like?

Comment: The login.ejs just provided a login button for Facebook login,
<a href="/auth/facebook"><img src="/images/fb.png" /></a>

But it actually seems to work now, the layout functionality seem to have been changed in Express 3 (see answer below). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/48

I am uncertain whether the above has been updated but it suggests that layout functionality has been deprecated in express 3.

As a result, I have been using ejs-locals to implement equivalent functionality:

https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals

Comment: I would add this as a comment to the question but lack the requisite reputation.

Comment: Yes, layouts and partials have been removed in Express 3. YOu need to use ejs-locals to get them back.

Comment: for anyone else looking `ejs-locals` is no longer maintained